# My Sql query to select distinct records with max column value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

[My database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T58z8.png)

I have this history table that maitains duplicate Panel_Number and its history.
I will need your help in getting a query which will give me distinct Panel_Number with its max(version) from the table.

eg:- Panel 0G3101 has 3 occurences in the table with different version 1,2,3. I only need to show in the resultset the Panel 0G3101 WITH MAX(VERSION) which is 3 in this case.

Likewise I need all distinct panel numbers with their max version  .

Comment: If your requirement is for `[mysql]` database don't include the  `[oracle]` tag. They are different products, and for this task they may have different solutions.

Comment: You can may be look into this, this has helped me previously. Hope it helps for you too. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an SQL fiddle I made for you](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d06bf/1). I added some arbitrary data, but the query will work properly with you.

The query should be:

```
SELECT
    id, 
    panel_number, 
    max(version) 
FROM 
    PANEL
GROUP BY
    panel_number
```

The result is like:

```
| id | panel_number | max(version) |

|----|--------------|--------------|

|  1 |       0G3101 |            3 |

|  4 |       0G3102 |            2 |
```

Comment: Thanks. but this does not work entirely as required. I might have not explained my requirement  precisely. In the image, for panel  no 0G3101, 0G3106, 0G3107, 0G3108 I am getting the version correctly but the latest records inserted which means the query shud return ids- 61.62,63,64 (which are at the end of the table )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Group by clause to solve your issue.

```
SELECT  panel_number, max(version) FROM PANEL GROUP BY panel_number
```

Comment: Sorry bud. I will need the lastest version of the panel number inserted which in this case is ids-   61.62,63,64 (which are at the end of the table )

Comment: Try the following one `SELECT  panel_number, version,max(id) FROM PANEL GROUP BY panel_number `

Comment: Update your question so we can help, and make some changes to the fiddle so we can know what you exactly want.

Answer (score -1):

Try these..work 100% click on query..

```
SELECT  panel_number, MAX(version) FROM PANEL GROUP BY panel_number
```

Comment: This does not meet the requirement, which is to select the record with the highest version for each business key (`panel_number`).